# Remove power line hum and noise from DC source

Tags: low-pass, emi-filtering

We are testing our device in a local RF compliance center next week.

I spoke with them on the phone and they suggested using a car battery instead of an AC powered DC supply.  The reason they gave was that their DC source is noisy.

TI don't want to introduce stray noise and causing our product to fail. I want to clean the DC signal, getting rid of both power line hum and any high frequency EMI.

I was looking at EMI feed-through filters and external chokes but couldn't find anything less than about 10kHz, any recommendations?

How can I remove power line hum on a DC signal?

Comment: Isn't this where people use dual common-mode chokes (on V+ and V-) with capacitors to form an LC filter specifically designed to remove/reduce 50-60Hz power line noise?

Comment: Actually just the common mode choke coil itself is enough to effectively cancel out common mode (low freq AC noise on both lines at the same time) noise.

Comment: http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/26to30.ashx